# use $.each function to traverse json_encoded twig array AND MAINTAIN ORIGINAL KEYS

Tags: jquery, arrays, symfony, twig, each

Using Symfony2.3.4 with Twig and jQuery.

Short story: I have a php variable which is an **array(integer, string)** *asorted* and then sent to a twig template. There I need to traverse it as a jquery **var** using **$.each** function. So far:

```
//.html.twig  
var options = getJSonObject('{{ options|json_encode()|escape('js')|raw }}');  
$.each(options, function(k, v) {
    console.log(k);  
    console.log(v);  
});
```

Just in case:

**getJSonObject(value)** has only: `return $.parseJSON(value.replace(/&quot;/ig, '"'));` inside.

Problem: **console.log(k);** outputs *0, 1, 2, 3* and so on, when it should actually output something like *112, 113, 137, 138, 63* which are the actual keys in the original **options** twig array after the *asorting*.

I tried to explain it as concise and clear as I could, any doubts or insights, post.

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

What does your `console.log(v);` is showing? Only the string or an object/array with integer and number?

Did you tried to see what `options` is containing after the `$.parsJSON`? And maybe before in your php or twig? Just to see if you still get you keys (e.g: 112, 113, etc.) at any phase of the process.

Tell me what this debug statements show you =)